# How sort array in ascending order but put 0 at last?

Tags: c#

sort array in that manner that sorted array's member starts in ascending order but o value comes at last in c#

```
ulong[] arr = new ulong[30];

arr[0]=13325647855656;
arr[1]=65897426666332;
arr[2]=00685956265661;
arr[4]=0;
```

then output must be

```
arr[0]=00685956265661;
arr[1]=13325647855656;
arr[2]=65897426666332;
arr[4]=0;
```

Comment: And what have you tried? If you know how to sort array then its not that difficult

Comment: @Bingo: I have tried Array.sort(arr); but it gives 0 first.

Comment: question: why do you need it like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf.aspx) with this custom [comparison delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx):

```
Array.Sort(arr, (u1, u2) =>
    {
        if (u1 == 0 && u2 == 0) return 0;
        else if (u1 == 0) return ulong.MaxValue.CompareTo(u2);
        else if (u2 == 0) return u1.CompareTo(ulong.MaxValue);
        else return u1.CompareTo(u2);
    });
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/yI3c9e)

If you want to use Linq (`ToArray()` needs to create an additonal array internally), i would use:

```
arr = arr.OrderBy(x => x == 0).ThenBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Comment: in this case, its not actually needed to compare it Max, and the elses are redundant

Answer (score 7):

you can use `Linq` `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`

```
ulong[] arr = new ulong[30];
arr[0] = 13325647855656;
arr[1] = 65897426666332;
arr[2] = 00685956265661;
arr[4] = 0;

var results = arr.OrderBy(x => x == 0).ThenBy(x => x);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ZeroIsBigComparer : System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<ulong>
    {
        public int Compare(ulong x, ulong y)
        {
            if (x == y) return 0;
            if (x == 0) return 1;
            if (y == 0) return -1;
            return x.CompareTo(y);
        }
    }
```

then

```
var comparer = new ZeroIsBigComparer();
arr = arr.OrderBy(x => x, comparer).ToArray();
```

Comment: If you want to use Linq (and create an additonal array) anyway, i would prefer `arr.OrderBy(x => x==0).ThenBy(x => x)`.

Comment: I'm a big fan of Linq, but in this case it's not the right tool since OP wants to sort that array, he don't want to create somewhing new. There are already methods to sort arrays (or lists), so why not use them when they are more efficient?

Comment: though, yours is probably the best way to do it.